# Validating or Validated event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some textboxes databound to a BindingSource to custom business object. Databinding is done as the following code-

```
  txtBookNo.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "BookNo", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, null, "G", GlobalVariables.CurrentCultureInfo);
```

Now I would like to validate user input. Which event is best for this purpose- Textbox.Validating or Textbox.Validated? And, what should be DatasourceUpdateMode- OnPropertyChanged or OnValidation?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "And, what should be DatasourceUpdateMode- OnPropertyChanged or OnValidation" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `Validating` is fired just before the validation process starts, this is the place to put the actual validation code.
- `Validated` is fired after the validation process has finished and is designed to be the place to something based on the validation result.

If `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` is used then:

> Data source is updated whenever the value of the control property changes.

If `DatasourceUpdateMode.OnValidation` is used then:

> Data source is updated when the control property is validated,
>   After validation, the value in the control property will also be re-formatted.

If you want only valid (that means it has been validated by your code) data to be sent to your custom business objects you shuld use `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation`.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx) is an article explaining how to do validation in Windows Forms.

Comment: Thanks juhan_h for the reply and MSDN reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Textbox.Validating or Textbox.Validated?**

as it is explained on [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx). *Textbox.Validating* is the best place to put *validating process*.

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, 
            System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   string errorMsg;
   bool valid = /*do some validation*/;
   if(!valid)
  {
     // to cancel validating
     e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```